# Pipes in unix - is the value implicitly supplied as an argument?

Tags: unix, grep, pipe

I would like to delete all files ending in .orig recursively from the current directory.

Will this do the trick?

`ls -R | grep ".orig$" | rm`

Are the results of grep passed implicitly as an argument to rm here?

Comment: Parsing `ls` output isn't a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.orig" -exec rm "{}" \;
```

Seems to work for me, but it might be a good idea to test it with `echo` instead of `rm` first ;)

`ls -R` wont five quite the correct format output to pass directly to rm (through grep), as it lists files separately for each dir like:

```
.:
local1.orig local

./dir:
nested1.orig nested2.orig
```

If you wanted to do something similar using grep, you would need to use `xargs` like this:

```
grep ".orig$" | xargs rm
```

Comment: Just removed the `i` from `-iname`, as that would also match "file.Orig", "file.oRiG", etc (I'm so used to typing `-iname`, as I normally want to match without case sensitivity when I search).

Comment: Might be worth putting the {} as "{}" to handle filenames with spaces?

Comment: That's a good point, though the `rm` would fail if it tried to remove a directory.

Comment: The rm would fail if it tried to remove a directory; but it would successfully delete a directory symlink, or sockets, or named pipes...

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not.  But that is the purpose of `xargs`:

```
ls -R | grep ".orig$" | xargs rm -i
```

will do what you want.  The `-i` is not necessary, but is a good idea to use the first time you run this.  (It will prompt you to delete a file.  If you are confident that the answer is always yes, abort and re-run without the `-i`.)

Comment: I don't think this would work recursively, for the reason described in my answer (regarding the way nested files are listed by `ls -R`).